# Plotting multiple columns on one line graph

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plot

I'm trying to create a line chart to compare performance of different programs for a specific operation. I'm looking at the Median Cycle time for each program on each day of operation. I was able to create a dataframe with the information organized how I want (the `Test` DF).
I tried `med.groupby(['Close_Date','Program']).median()['Cycle Time'].unstack().plot()` however received the following *Key Error: Cycle Time*.

I shared my current code and printed the first 20 lines of the dataframe I'm using. Again, the dataframe is organized find, I'm trying to figure out how to plot the median Cycle Time for each program on each date by program.

Thank you in advance.

```
#Filter for Bad

Filter1 = df[df['Problem_Type'] == 'Bad']
Filter2 = df[df['Request_Text'].str.contains('bad', na=False, case = 'false')]
df2=pd.concat([Filter1,Filter2], ignore_index=True, axis=0)

#Create DataFrame of Median Cycle Time

med = df2[['Close_Date','Program','Cycle Time']]
med['Close_Date']=pd.to_datetime(med['Close_Date'], format='%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')
med['Close_Date']=med['Close_Date'].dt.strftime('%Y/%m/%d')
med2=med.groupby(med.Program,med.Close_Date)[['Cycle Time']].median()

Test = med.groupby(['Close_Date'],['Program'])['Cycle Time'].median()
```

```
Close_Date  Program        
2019-06-24  A                  0.600000
            B                  0.491667
            C                  0.416667
            D                  0.500000
            E                  0.300000
            F                  3.158333
            G                  0.316667
2019-06-25  A                  1.433333
            B                  0.266667
            C                  0.016667
            D                  1.016667
            E                  0.791667
            F                  2.333333
2019-06-26  A                  0.866667
            B                  21.550000
            C                  0.933333
            D                  1.291667
            E                  0.166667
            F                  1.216667
            G                  2.366667
Name: Cycle Time, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Try `med.groupby(['Close_Date','Program'])['Cycle Time'].median().unstack().plot()`?

Comment: Weird, this code above should work: `med.groupby(['Close_Date','Program'])['Cycle Time'].median().unstack().plot()`, I was able to replicate it here using the sample data above.

Comment: What results are you seeing as the output of: `med.groupby(['Close_Date','Program']).median()`?

Comment: I honestly don't know what happened. I rebooted my console and ran it twice. First two times it error'd out but the third time it worked just fine.